# Specflow for Report tests?

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, specflow

We've been running into a number of issues with our reports lately, duplicate entries, not excluding the right information, missing information etc. I was thinking of creating test suits with specflow for the reports.

The reports are displayed in ssrs or crystal reports, so full end to end tests are probably off the table. The views and procedures that these reports rely on though should be testable, I was thinking of something along the lines of these lines for the test definitions:

```
Scenario: Some Report contains expected values
    Given I execute uspSomeReport with:
    | Field | Value    |
    | From  | 1/1/2015 |
    | To    | 1/1/2016 |
    Then the result should contain:
    | Id    | Name  |
    | 3456  | John  |
    | 98345 | Barry |

Scenario: Address not duplicated
    Given I execute uspSomeReport with:
    | Field | Value    |
    | From  | 1/1/2015 |
    | To    | 1/1/2016 |
    Then Address, Postcode should be unique
```

I guess my questions are does anyone have any experience writing tests for reporting? Are there any obvious problems with an approach like this? Any better ideas?

Comment: Try the approach and if you have any problem post here

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely write a test as you indicate to feed the input params to your report SP and validate the results. However, a few things to consider:

1. Are the issues you've been encountering due to the data returned by the sp or actually problems in the report itself? Either could be causing data to not be present or to be duplicated. There could be a visibility property in the report definition or a grouping error causing problems that simply checking the sp would not discover. If you know the issues are in the sp, then testing at that layer makes perfect sense. Just be aware that the data can be correct, but the report display incorrect. If you need to test the output of the actual report, one option may be to use the report's export functionality to export the formatted report and compare it a known correct template for validation. Tools such as Beyond Compare allow smart comparison of many different file formats (csv, pdf, excel, etc.). Doing validation of the actual report output this way is more complex and error-prone than simply testing the sp, so you may want to start with testing the sp and add the bulk of your scenarios here and then have a smaller number of tests validating the report output if the benefit is worth the cost of implementing and maintaining this type of tests.
2. If you do move forward with SpecFlow, remember that a core benefit of SpecFlow tests are to enable collaboration and serve as living documentation, clearly identifying to stakeholders how your system works. If this is purely a desire to get some test coverage and you have no interest in the collaboration aspects, you may just want to consider a simple unit test of the sp. However, if you are looking for the collaborative benefits, i would recommend making your scenarios titles more descriptive of how the report works. For example, in you first example, you might want to consider something like "Records that fall on or within the date range are included in the results" or your second, "for each record returned, the record's address will be listed once". It may seem insignificant, but writing your scenario titles as product requirements makes your SpecFlow tests much more valuable in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, most of the technical issues are with the sp istelf, I believe the reports themselves are fairly thin "view layers".

Comment: For 2, I'm not sure how much we will leverage it as collaboration with the customer directly but it is a nice possibility. Getting the requirements correct has been a major pain point though, just getting the report developers to think in testing terms might be a win. It isn't "real developers" working on the reports so unit testing seemed a lot more complicated than what specflow allows us to achieve with me writing the backend code and them writing the tests.